# Scala Collection Framework design

Tags: scala, collections

I'm looking at Scala Collections implementation in 2.12 and have some question about the design. There are some "abstractions types" used in there:

```
$Coll$Like
Gen$Coll$Like
Gen$Coll$
```

As far as I understand the `Gen$Coll$Like` traits exist solely for purpose of reusing declarations (not definitions), i.e. all methods in `Gen$Coll$Like` traits are abstract.

`$Coll$Like` in turn declares a few abstract methods and implement the rest of the `Gen$Coll$Like` methods through them. Besides that `$Coll$Like`-traits have additional type parameter `+Repr` which I believe  is for cases like `SeqLike[Char, String]` so we can look at `String` as `Seq[Char]`.

The most questionable traits are `Gen$Coll$`. I do not really understand the point of them. In the hierarchy of `Seq` all `Gen$Coll$` traits are empty till `GenTraversableOnce` (also, I expected `GenTraversableOnce` to be named `GenTraversableOnceLike` since it provides abstract method declarations only):

```
GenSeq <--- GenIterable <--- GenTraversable <--- GenTraversableOnce
```

Can you explain the purpose of `Gen$Coll$` traits? The example of where 
 `Gen$Coll$` actually useful (for any purpose) would be highly appreciate.

Comment: Have a look at Scala 2.13 refactoring

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is a very good place for questions about design rationale in general, and this question is pretty vague.

Comment: @TravisBrown Let me try to elaborate. Having a look at the traits `scala.collections.GenSeq`, `scala.collection.GenIterable`, `scala.collection.GenTraversable` I found that they contain no method definitions, but simply extend `Like` trait, but `GenTraversableOnce` contain general traversable methods declarations like `foreach`, `fold`, etc... Do you know the idea of introducing those traits with no methods? Are they reserved for future or just markers?

Comment: @St.Antario The [collections design docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/architecture.html) do explain this—the `Gen` types abstract over parallel vs. sequential implementations.

Comment: @TravisBrown So since we have two kind of `Gen` traits (considering `Seq` for simplicity): `GenSeqLike` and `GenSeq`. The `GenSeq` is declared as trait `GenSeq[+A] extends GenSeqLike[A, GenSeq[A]] with GenIterable[A] with Equals with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, GenSeq]`. The only purpose of the `GenSeq` trait is to combine all other `Gen` traits together (in this case `GenSeqLike` and `GenIterable`) to define all operations that can be applied to `Seq` either sequentially or in parallel. Sort of that?

Comment: "I'm looking at Scala Collections implementation in 2.12..." _immediately clicks close tab_

Comment: @Lasf I agree the Scala Collections implementation is complicated, but I do sure there was some reason for that...